# How do I typecast an object created through reflection to run a method?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm having trouble to find how to typecast the dynamically created class while using reflection.

```
String s;
...
Class unknownClass = Class.forName(s); 
Constructor defaultConstructor = unknownClass.getConstructor(null);

Object retobj = defaultConstructor.newInstance(null);
retobj.Writeout(); // This won't work since;
```

The object class does not have a method called Writeout, but that is the name of the method which is shared by nine other possible classes that is dynamically created here (needless to say every Writeout method does a seperate thing). Any suggestions ? Thx in advance for your time.

Comment: Why dont you use an interface for all classes implementing Writeout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use reflection Luke...

```
Method writeOutMethod = unknownClass.getMethod("Writeout", new Class[]{});
writeOutMethod.invoke(retobj, new Object[]{});
```

Or, ensure that your objects implement a well known *interface* (the clean approach).

Answer (score 1):

Cast it:

```
 ((YourObjectWithThatMethod) retobj).Writeout();
```

EDIT (see the comment from Kevin Welker):

If all of your 9 classes implement the same interface, you can cast every class to that interface:

```
 ((YourInterface) retobj).Writeout();
```

Comment: or you need an interface for the 9+1 classes that all have that method, and use the above technique with the interface.

Answer (score 1):

The 9 classes should all implement a single interface (let's call it `Output`) which declares the `writeOut()` method. The code would thus be:

```
Output retobj = (Output) defaultConstructor.newInstance(null);
retobj.writeOut();
```

Note that you could just use `unknownClass.newInstance()` to invoke the no-arg constructor.

Side note: please respect tha Java naming conventions: methods start with a lower-case letter.

Answer (score 1):

If all nine classes share a super-class or an interface which declares/implements `writeOut` then you can cast `retobj` to that interface and then call it.

```
public interface Writable {
    public void writeOut();
}
```

Then each class needs to have in the class declaration.

```
class MyClass implements Writable {
}
```

Then you can say

```
((Writable) retobj).writeOut();
```